# Select greatest number of unique pairs from table

Tags: sql, algorithm, t-sql, duplicates

I have the following table:

```
| a | b |
|---|---|
| 2 | 4 | x
| 2 | 5 | 
| 3 | 1 | x
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 | x
| 7 | 5 | 
| 7 | 4 | 
|---|---|
```

I want to select the greatest number of unique pairs possible where neither a or b are repeated.  So the entries with x's next to them should be what the select would grab.  Any ideas how to do this?

Currently I have some SQL that will do the opposite, select those that aren't unique and delete them but it has not been working the way I want it to.  This is the SQL I have right now, but I think I'm going to scrap it and work at it from the angle I have stated above.

```
delete t
from #temp2 t
    where (exists(select * from #temp2
                 where (b = t.b 
                    and a < t.a))
  or exists(select * from #temp2
                 where a = t.a 
                    and (b < t.b and ) and 
          (not exists(select * from #temp2
                 where b = t.b
                    and a < t.a)
  or not exists(select * from #temp2
                 where a = t.a
                    and b < t.b))
```

Thanks!

Comment: A solution for the maximum matching will do the work. Although I don't know exactly how to convert it to SQL...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: Would {`3,1`, `6,4`, `7,5`} also be a solution?  Or {`3,1`, `6,5`, `7,4`}?

Comment: I would just use a DataReader and two HashSet in .NET

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that being non-unique and unique are mutually exclusive and will encompass all records in your table. If so, use your existing script, write it to a CTE, then join to the CTE from your source table selecting those records not in the CTE.

```
With Non_Unique_Records as (
--Insert your existing script here
)

Select t.a
    , t.b

From #temp2 t
    Left Outer Join Non_Unique_Records CTE
        on t.a = CTE.a
            and t.b = CTE.b

Where CTE.b is null
```

Then just delete the records that the Select statement returns.

Comment: What do you mean by "Insert your existing script here"? Do you mean the code that will create the @temp2 table?

Comment: In your question, you said "Currently I have some SQL that will do the opposite, select those that aren't unique". Insert the SQL script which correctly selects those that are not unique where it says "--insert your existing script here"

Comment: Ahh, well unfortunately the code I have that selects those that are not unique does not work correctly. That is why I want to approach it from the other way.